# Density Value for each Return

Tags: r, kernel-density

I have a dataframe "foo" looking like this

```
Date       Return
1998-01-01  0.02
1998-01-02  0.04
1998-01-03 -0.02
1998-01-04 -0.01
1998-01-05  0.02
...
1998-02-01  0.1
1998-02-02 -0.2
1998-02-03 -0.1
etc.
```

I would like to add to this dataframe a new column showing me the density value of the corresponding return. I tried:

```
foo$density <- for(i in 1:length(foo$Return)) density(foo$Return, 
from = foo$Return[i], to = foo$Return[i], n = 1)$y
```

But it didn't work. I really have difficulty applying a "function" to each row. But maybe there is also another way to do it, not using density()?

What I essentially would like to do is to extract the fitted density values from density() to the returns in foo. If I just do plot(density(foo$Return)) it gives me the curve, however I would like to have the density values attached to the returns.

@Joris:

```
foo$density <- density(foo$Return, n=nrow(foo$Return))$y
```

calculates something, however seems to return wrong density values.

Thank you for helping me out!
Dani

Comment: what you are doing doesn't make any sense. The returns are a distribution for which you want the probability density, so you supply all of the returns to `density`, not one at a time as you are trying to do.

Comment: @Gavin: I know, however if I apply density() to the returns, all returns should have an attached density value, don't they? As Joris pointed out, density() returns a grid, so what I wanted to do in the first place was wrong.

Comment: It wasn't clear that you wanted to evaluate the density *at* the given points, as both Joris and I missed that.

Comment: my second answer addresses the thrust of your question using a different approach to that of @Joris using only base R. Not sure if that is any further use to you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On second thought, forget about the density function, I suddenly realized what you wanted to do. Most density functions return a grid, so don't give you the evaluation in the exact points. If you want that, you can eg use the `sm` package:

```
require(sm)
foo <- data.frame(Return=rpois(100,5))
foo$density <- sm.density(foo$Return,eval.points=foo$Return)$estimate
# the plot
id <- order(foo$Return)
hist(foo$Return,freq=F)
lines(foo$Return[id],foo$density[id],col="red")
```

If the number of different values is not that big, you can use ave() :

```
foo$counts <- ave(foo$Return,foo$Return,FUN=length)
```

If the purpose is to *plot* a density function, there's no need to calculate it like you did. Just use

```
plot(density(foo$Return))
```

Or, to add a histogram underneath (mind the option `freq=F`)

```
hist(foo$Return,freq=F)
lines(density(foo$Return),col="red")
```

Comment: @Dani : I edited my function, as you're apparently looking for the density values of the specific points. density() evaluates a grid, so you'll never get the actual numbers out for your data points.

Comment: Thanks very much! The sm package seems to work much better! But when I draw the plot, my density curve lies underneath the histogram, so kind of underestimating the peak (much lower density values than what the histogram would suggest). What I mean by that: plot(density()) returns larger density values than sm.density. Shouldn't the two curves look similar when plotting them?

Comment: @Dani: They're two different algorithms, and both are approximations. If you have something specific in mind, you should ask that. As you say "peak", set the method to "sj" in the sm.density function. The standard option is optimal for data with an underlying normal distribution.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to `sm.density` is to evaluate the density on a finer grid than default, and use `approx` or `approxfun` to give the interpolated values of the density at the `Returns` you want. Here is an example with dummy data:

```
set.seed(1)
foo <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), as.Date("2010-12-31"),
                             by = "days"),
                  Returns = rnorm(365))
head(foo)
## compute the density, on fin grid (512*8 points)
dens <- with(foo, density(Returns, n = 512 * 8))
```

At this point, we could use `approx()` to interpolate the `x` and `y` components of the returned density, but I prefer `approxfun()` which does the same thing, but returns a function which we can then use to do the interpolation. First, generate the interpolation function:

```
## x and y are components of dens, see str(dens)
BAR <- with(dens, approxfun(x = x, y = y))
```

Now you can use `BAR()` to return the interpolated density at any point you wish, e.g. for the first `Returns`:

```
> with(foo, BAR(Returns[1]))
[1] 0.3268715
```

To finish the example, add the density for each datum in `Returns`:

```
> foo <- within(foo, Density <- BAR(Returns))
> head(foo)
        Date    Returns   Density
1 2010-01-01 -0.6264538 0.3268715
2 2010-01-02  0.1836433 0.3707068
3 2010-01-03 -0.8356286 0.2437966
4 2010-01-04  1.5952808 0.1228251
5 2010-01-05  0.3295078 0.3585224
6 2010-01-06 -0.8204684 0.2490127
```

To see how well the interpolation is doing, we can plot the density and the interpolated version and compare. Note we have to sort `Returns` because to achieve the effect we want, `lines` needs to see the data in *increasing* order:

```
plot(dens)
with(foo, lines(sort(Returns), BAR(sort(Returns)), col = "red"))
```

Which gives something like this:
[image: Density (in black) and interpolated version (in red)]

As long as the density is evaluated at sufficiently fine a set of points (512*8 in the above example) you shouldn't have any problems and will be hard pushed to tell the difference between the interpolated version and the real thing. If you have "gaps" in the values of your `Returns` then you might find that, as `lines()` just joins the points you ask it to plot, that straight line segments might not follow the black density at the locations of the gaps. This is just an artefact of the gaps and how `lines()` works, not a problem with the interpolation.

Comment: Thank you very much you two, that is all very helpful!

Comment: But this will not work if an extrapolation has to take place (unlikely in this example here).

Answer (score 2):

If we ignore the `density` issue, which @Joris expertly answers, you don't seem to have grasped how to set up a loop. What you are returning from the loop is the value `NULL`. This is the value that is being inserted in `foo$density` and that won't not work because it is the `NULL`, which means it is an empty component, i.e. it doesn't exists as far as R is concerned. See `?'for'` for further details.

```
> bar <- for(i in 1:10) {
+     i + 1
+ }
> bar
NULL

> foo <- data.frame(A = 1:10, B = LETTERS[1:10])
> foo$density <- for(i in seq_len(nrow(foo))) {
+     i + 1
+ }
> head(foo) ## No `density`
  A B
1 1 A
2 2 B
3 3 C
4 4 D
5 5 E
6 6 F
```

If you want to insert the return value for each iteration of the loop, you must do the assignment *inside* the loop, and that means you should pre-allocate the storage space before you enter the loop, e.g. the above loop if we wanted to have `i + 1` for `i` in 1,...,10, we could do this:

```
> bar <- numeric(length = 10)
> for(i in seq_along(bar)) {
+     bar[i] <- i + 1
+ }
> bar
 [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

Of course, you would not do such a calculation as this via a loop, because R is vectorized and will work with vectors of numbers rather than you having to code each computation element by element as you might in C or other programming languages.

```
> bar <- 1:10 + 1
> bar
 [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

Notice that R has turned `1` into a vector of `1`s of sufficient length to allow the computation to proceed, something known as *recycling* in R-speak.

Sometimes, you might need to iterate over an object with a loop or using one of the `s|l|t|apply()` family, but most often you will find a function that works for an entire vector of data in one go. This is one of the advantages of R over other programming languages, but does require you to get your head into **vectorized** mode.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to obtain density values.

```
foo$density <- density(foo$Return, n=length(foo$Return))$y
```